# Eclipse message saying List cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying the following code in eclipse:

```
public class A {    
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

However it gives me an error saying: List cannot be resolved to a type and ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type.

Is there some library I need to add and how do I do that?

Comment: First you must import the classes.

Comment: Is `java.util.List` present in your imports?

Comment: By the way, this has nothing to do with Eclipse and all to do with basic Java.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for auto importing.

Answer (score 30):

Put the following at the top of your source file:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) is an explanation of what packages are and how the `import` statement works.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to `either import` the packages in which these classes are present, `or write the entire path.`

### 1. import :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

### 2. Full path:

public class A {

`java.util.List<Integer>` intList = new `java.util.ArrayList<Integer>()`;

}

### 3. In Eclipse IDE,

use `ctrl + shift + O` to import.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it may also be that the Java Build Path is not correctly set for your project.

Go to the project properties (Right click on project name in workspace and then click on Properties) and in the "Java Build Path" check if the `JRE System Library` is set to `unbound`.

If that's the case, change it to one of the Java SDK available on your machine. The address to download those is [this one.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need the following 2 imports

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Do you use an IDE? Most IDE's have helps that will suggest fixes like these imports.

Comment: Oops, missed the first line, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Placed the cursor into the place where error is showing then eclipse will suggest some quick fixes through a dialog box. In the dialog box select the option "Import arraylist". Then Eclipse will automatically import.

Answer (score 0):

Even after importing the required packages, if the error persists then just click on Project in the Menu Bar and then click on Clean. Then right-click on your project from the project explorer and refresh your project.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.List intList = new java.util.ArrayList();

This resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So I'am suffering from the same probleme so you need to insall jre 1.8

1 - go to this link and install the JRE 1.8 https://www.java.com/fr/download/manual.jsp
2 - go to eclipse goto project proprities --> build path ->Library > Edit Alternatif JRE choose from your directory the file you have insall from presse finish apply apply and close this will slove the probleme

Answer (score -2):

You are declaring List object outside any method.
Move it inside a method and it will work.

Comment: List variable? Really?