# compilation error in generic list

Tags: java, generics

When I use the below code , I do not get compilation error

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList <Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list.add(4);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(12);
        System.out.println(list);
        int sum=2;
        for (int i:list){
            sum+=i;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }
    }
}
```

but when I use the below code , I get error in the format of the generic List (I do not know why ):

```
import java.util.List;
public class C {


public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // List cannot be resolved to a type
        list.add(4);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(12);
        System.out.println(list);
        int sum=2;
        for (int i:list){
            sum+=i;
            System.out.println(sum);
        }  
    }
}
```

How to do to fix the second code ?

Comment: Probably you are missing the import `java.util.List`.

Comment: I did it it does not work brother

Comment: @code I can't see a import in your second program brother.

Comment: I did add java.util.List in my code but it did not work .. that is why I removed it brother

Comment: @code Update the code if you have changed it brother.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse message saying List cannot be resolved to a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065517/eclipse-message-saying-list-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Comment: The code itself compiles just fine, except for the missing import statements: The one for the List interface and the ArrayList implementation class.

Comment: missing import `import java.util.ArrayList;`

Comment: know it works .. God bless you all brothers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the below import statements to your code,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

---

See this line in your code,

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

This line uses the `List` interface AND the `ArrayList` class. So, you need to have both of them imported in your file.