# ArrayList<> cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, typeerror

I am struggling with a homework assignment in my java course.  The problem I am having is with constructing instance data.  My professor has given us a video to watch and I am following each step, but Eclipse is saying that my ArrayList cannot be resolved to a type.

```
import.java.util.ArrayList;

public class Campaign {

    private String candidateName;
    private ArrayList<DonorList> donors;

    public Campaign(String  name)
    {
        //TODO Initialize all of the instance data
        candidateName = name;
        donors = new ArrayList<DonorList>();
    }
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you import the class?

Comment: Where's import? Also you can do `private ArrayList<DonorList> donors;` declaration to `private List<DonorList> donors;` just a suggestion

Comment: Since you're working in Eclipse, you can hover over the red-underlined code and select the item "Import 'ArrayList' (java.util)" to fix your problem.

Comment: I do have the import statement, sorry for not including that in the example code.

Comment: please **edit your question** to include all of the relevant code

Answer (score 15):

You probably need to add an import statement.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

This goes after your package declaration.  This let's the system know what an ArrayList is and what methods it has available.

Hope that was it!

Comment: Yes I do have an import statement.. Sorry for not including that.

Answer (score 2):

Hello you have made a lot of mistakes.

1) There is dot after import.
2) No main method

and many other.

Though I have corrected all of them . Hope this finally works.

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 

public class Campaign {
    private String candidateName;
    private ArrayList<String> donors;


    public Campaign(String name, ArrayList<String> a1) {
        candidateName = name;
        donors = a1;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList <String> aa = new ArrayList <String>();
        aa.add("Ram");
        aa.add("Sita");

        Campaign obj = new Campaign("Nischal",aa);
        System.out.println(obj.candidateName + " "+ obj.donors);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a dot after the import keyword, you should write it as

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

if it doesn't work even after this correction, then it's probably because of a bug in your editor.
just close your code editor and reopen it, then the import statement will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For auto importing in Eclipse IDE, you should press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

**Resource Link:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/11065545/2293534